# Why won't Python's socket.recv() return -1

Tags: python, sockets, recv

If I close a server socket while in a `s.recv_into()` loop from a client, I keep getting 0 from `recv_into()` infinitely.

As I understand, the only way to know a socket is closed was not through the Python socket mechanism itself, but using select / poll / etc.

What's the rational of not returning -1 when the socket is closed by the other side? Why can't I properly differentiate "no data currently" from "no one there anymore"?

**EDIT:**

Perhaps the correct question is - why is no exception thrown when using `recv()`, if the other side terminated the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `recv_into` is just a wrapper of the C system call by name `recv`. The return value of `0` is not an erroneous condition!

From Linux manuals, [`recv(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> These calls return the number of bytes received, or -1 if an error
>   occurred.    In the event of an error, errno is set to indicate the
>   error.
>
> When  a  stream  socket  peer  has performed an orderly shutdown,
>   the return    value will be 0 (the traditional "end-of-file" return).
>
> Datagram sockets in various domains (e.g., the UNIX  and  Internet 
>   domains)    permit  zero-length datagrams.  When such a datagram is
>   received, the return    value is 0.
>
> The value 0 may also be returned if the requested number of bytes
>   to receive    from a stream socket was 0.

For error cases, Python will not return `-1`, instead it will raise an appropriate exception.

For a stream sockets you must break the loop whenever `recv_*` returns a value that indicates that 0 bytes were received. There is no point for checking `-1`, but  in case you do want to be extra certain, you can naturally use `while sock.recv_into(....) > 0:` or similar.

The various `read` calls in Python work in similar fashion.

Comment: What if the server is calculating a response? How can I differentiate "no data yet" vs "no one there anymore" if they both return 0?

Comment: @Jay did you read the black text on the yellow? It lists 3 cases where the return value is 0. Which of those cases does *your* case fall under?

Comment: unorderly shutdown (ctrl-c on the server socket)

Comment: @Jay there's no truely reliable way to decide whether a peer is alive or not. The best you can do is to implement some ping mechanism.

Comment: There is **no case** where you can get **return value of 0** for "no data yet".

Comment: What do I get in this case?

Comment: You will get **blocking** call or **exception if the socket is non-blocking**.

Comment: Is there a reason I should stay in blocking mode, instead of just checking the result / exception mechanism of a non blocking socket? This looks like the right way

Comment: @Jay that totally depends on what you are trying to achieve. In general non-blocking programming is harder.

Answer (score 1):

> If I close a server socket while in a `s.recv_into()` loop from a client, I keep getting 0 from `recv_into()` infinitely.

Yes, as expected. A closed connection is indicated by 0, not -1.

> As I understand, the only way to know a socket is closed was not through the Python socket mechanism itself, but using select / poll / etc.

No, that's not true. Simply calling `recv` in a non-blocking mode will do the job without involving any selector mechanism. In a non-blocking mode the "no data yet" state will be indicated by an appropriate exception (note that you have to inspect that exception, it's not the only case when `recv` throws).

However this doesn't mean that the peer is still alive (the default TCP timeout is 15 minutes AFAIK). This cannot be reliably detected. The best you can do is to implement some pinging protocol over the wire.

> What's the rational of not returning -1 when the socket is closed by the other side?

For syscalls (such as `recv`) the -1 return code is (typically) reserved for errors. However Python translates these into exceptions (and so AFAIK you will never get -1 in Python).

Anyway 0 is not an error. It's an information that the other side closed the connection. Perhaps this is a completely valid situation, there's no way for Python (or any other language) to know that.

Comment: Does recv() in non-blocking mode return -1 if the socket was closed?

Comment: @Jay As I said: recv() never returns -1. When connection is closed recv() always returns 0. When connection is open and socket is blocking then recv() waits for data. If conenction is open and socket is non-blocking then recv() will throw an exception when data is not available.

Comment: But that Exception still means either no data yet or connection closed, correct?

Comment: @Jay no, the exception in recv() will never mean "connection closed". As I said: only return value 0 means that the connection is closed. Is that really unclear what I've posted? However the exception may mean other things, you have to inspect the exception object.

Comment: You're saying that, in non blocking mode, an Exception means no data, whereas 0 means connection closed? That sounds workable

Comment: @Jay yes, that's what I'm saying. I've updated the answer.